# Should ticket/PR number be in commit header

Tags: git

I see many people put the ticket/PR number in the git commit header. I think it only adds clutter when you read `git log` because as human those numbers do not tell you anything.

Putting the numbers in the commit message (anything after the blank line) will make much more sense as it will keep the record that this commit fixes/related to that issue and will allow for easy search but will leave the log clean and readable.

I'm trying to find the answer to why people do that?

Comment: Our team uses it with [Jira/Git integration](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/4984/git-integration-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview). That way it's easy to see if a bug has any commits or PR's

Comment: Maybe some tools can only read the ticket/PR number from the git commit header and not the message?

Comment: I am not familiar with the term "commit header."  What is that?  Anyway, the utility of having an issue number in the Git commit message should be obvious: Anyone can now search your Git history by ticket number, which can be useful when trying to pinpoint when certain features were carried out.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen "commit header" is an unofficial way of referring to the first line of the commit message. It has a special significance since it's what shows up when you do a `git log --oneline`.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim You might want to include this information in your answer.  I've been using Git for years, and I was clueless about this :P

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is off topic here on stack overflow because it asks for an opinion. If it makes sense for you to do it, do it, if it doesn't, then don't.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen For me, it doesn't make sense to put it in the first line because the first line is what you see why watching the log. I'm looking for an explanation of why smart people are still doing it, for example in the Angular project.

Comment: Then you should ask the people in the angular project. Their reasons are their own, someone else may have different reasons or different opinions. You can't get an *answer* to this question, just someones opinion.

Comment: What you're calling the commit "header", Git itself calls the commit *subject* (or sometimes *title*). See the description for the `%s` directive under PRETTY FORMATS in the `git log` documentation.

Comment: Yes the subject line shouldn't be referenced to as "header" (even informally) since it can be easily confused wit `trailers` which are modeled after RFC 822 header lines (see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-interpret-trailers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you in principle, the less clutter in the commit Subject line the better. I wouldn't say though that these references are useless for humans though, because many tools can automatically link ticket ids to the corresponding ticket in a log overview (where oftentimes only the subject line is shown by default). Still, the subject line should provide enough context to reveal what the commit is about, without requiring the reader to follow links.

For GitHub ticket ids one has to be careful though, to not put them at the start of the line, because they start with a `#` which is interpreted as a comment line by git so it will not be included in the message.

I think technically the best solution would be to put related ticket numbers as "metadata" into commit message [trailers](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-interpret-trailers). If the industry could agree on common conventions there, tools could support that as well, but until that happens I suppose people will continue to use the subject line for ticket ids.

Answer (score 2):

This is asking for an opinion. I try to keep my commit messages self contained so that it makes sense to people without having to connect to github (after all, what use is a distributed SCM tool if you need to connect to a site to see what's going on). However, github provides some useful hooks to close bugs by number so a "closes #42" in a commit message is not an overkill but it should be in the description rather than the header.

Comment: I agree that this is opinion, but I hope to find reasons for opinions and not just opinions. I agree that both hook and simply keeping the history that a commit is related to an issue is a good idea, I just don't think to put it in the header really helps reading the log.

Comment: @IdoRan I agree.